# What are these London appetizers?

Tags: food-and-drink, london

No idea what these are, my first time in London. I didn't make the order.

1. The thing the egg (middle)
2. The rolled meat in slices (left)

I can mostly tell what's in them but what are the proper names?

[image]

Comment: So you didn't risk ordering the Toad in the Hole, or the Spotted Dick then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The middle item is a scotch egg (a hard-boiled egg enclosed in sausage meat, rolled in breadcrumbs, and fried), and the item on the left looks very much like a large sausage roll, sliced. (It could be Beef Wellington, but I think that’s too posh a dish to be served alongside the others in the picture!)

Comment: @Giorgio Yes it would, but often ‘home-made’ sausage rolls served in the better pubs etc are larger than the snack variety you normally buy in supermarkets and fast food outlets. http://www.goodhousekeeping.co.uk/food/recipes/giant-sausage-roll

Comment: The sausage based food item could also be described as a Sausage Plait by some people.https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/2667648/sausage-plait

Answer (score 1):

1. Scotch egg: cooked eggs swaddled in sausage meat, then breaded and fried.
2. Beef Wellington: fillet steak coated with pâté and duxelles, then wrapped in puff pastry and baked.

OR (agree with @Traveller)

2. Sausage roll, sliced: sausage rolled in pastry and baked (and that would be a rather large version !)

Comment: You can clearly see on the picture that there is no fillet in the leftmost dish. The pastry is filled throughout with relatively light (in colour) minced meat.

Comment: In the U.K. it would be pretty unusual to find beef wellington on the menu in most pub/bistro-type eateries, it’s generally quite an expensive dish so you’d probably only get it in the more upmarket places

Answer (score 1):

The second-left looks like chicken goujons. It is strips of chicken breast, in a (slightly) spicy breadcrumb coating, and fried. Fairly common buffet foot in pubs. The right-most are onion rings. Not sure what the second-right one is.

Comment: The second-from-left looks more like salt-and-pepper squid to me.